# How to pass tuples and structs using web3.py or blockchain explorers

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, web3py, etherscan

How should I pass the following arguments to `sendOFT` function in
[This](https://explorer.zksync.io/address/0xDAc7479e5F7c01CC59bbF7c1C4EDF5604ADA1FF2#contract) smart smart contract using python web3.py and block explorer?
Here are the data types:

[image: sendOFT arguments]

[image: FeeObj]

I get an error when I pass elements like this.
Here is a [sample](https://explorer.zksync.io/tx/0x2a8528aa80560887e972992ced08c70309e1f4729860e25b79afb90953629cc9) transaction and this is it's decoded input data:

[image: sample tx]

I would appreciate a complete input sample for both python web3.py(web3.js would be good as well) and Block Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

In web3.py, you can pass a Solidity `struct` as

- Tuple
- Dict
- [NamedTuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

For example:

```
contract TupleContract {
    struct T { int x; bool[2] y; address[] z; }
    struct S { uint a; uint[] b; T[] c; }

    function method(S memory s) public pure returns (S memory) {
        return s;
    }
}
```

If you pass struct as a tuple, arguments must be in the same order as they are in Solidity source code.

You would encode this for a smart contract call as following

```py
my_struct_t = (1, [False, False], ["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"])

my_struct_s = (1, [1, 1], [my_struct_t, my_struct_t])

tuple_contract.functions.method(my_struct_s).transact({...})
```

See [Web3.py documentation for more information](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.contract.html#how-do-i-pass-in-a-struct-as-a-function-argument).

As block explorers tend to be proprietary software, you need to contact the support desk of any block explorer to learn how to use their software, and this job should not be outsourced to the public community.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But my problem wasn't just passing structs. There were some special attributes in arguments and I had a problem passing proper data types to them. I would appreciate it if you take a look at the photos I provided in my question.

Comment: Your question does not contain a repeatable code, but is bunch of links to hard to read pages. Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and edit your question to make it easier to understand and include necessary technical details and code. I cannot read your mind to underestand what you think is a special attribute